# How can I load MAGE query modules in Memgraph?

Tags: python, c, graph-databases, memgraphdb

How can I load MAGE query modules in Memgraph? Is there a difference if a query module is written in Python or C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query modules can be written using C API ( `.so` modules), and Python API ( `.py` modules). Each file corresponds to one query module with one or more procedures within them. The names of these files will be mapped to the query module names. For example, a procedure `node_connectivity` in `nxalg.py` will be mapped to `nxalg.node_connectivity()` in the Cypher query language.

Once you start Memgraph, it will attempt to load query modules from all `.so` and `.py` files from the default (`/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules and /var/lib/memgraph/internal_modules`) directories.

MAGE modules are located at `/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules` and custom modules developed via Memgraph Lab at `/var/lib/memgraph/internal_modules`.

Memgraph can load query modules from additional directories if their path is added to the `--query-modules-directory flag` in the main configuration file (`/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf`) or supplied as a command-line parameter (e.g. when using Docker).

If you are supplying the additional directory as a parameter, do not forget to include the path to `/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules`, otherwise queries from that directory will not be loaded when Memgraph starts.

If a certain query module was added while Memgraph was already running, you need to load it manually using the `mg.load("module_name")` procedure within a query:

`CALL mg.load("py_example");`

If you want to reload all existing modules and load any newly added ones, use `mg.load_all()`:

`CALL mg.load_all();`

You can check if the query module has been loaded by using the `mg.procedures()` procedure within a query:

`CALL mg.procedures() YIELD *;`